# Is the gap between successive real roots of $x(t) = \frac{1}{30000 e^t} + \frac{2 e^{t/2} \cos (\sqrt{3}t/2)}{30000} $ eventually less than $5$?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{30000} \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^t}+ \frac{2}{30000} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\right), \quad t\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Arrange the roots of this function $x$ in increasing order. Let $t_n$ denote the $n$th root of the function. The sequence $\{t_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ begins with (rounded to one decimal place)
$$1.8, 5.4, 9.1, 12.7, 16.3, \ldots$$

Based on plotting some graphs using Wolfram Alpha, the function $x$ appears to have infinitely many roots. Does there exist a positive integer $N$ such that, for each positive integer $n \ge N$, 
$$t_{n + 1} \le t_n + 5?$$

Comment: The first term is negligible for large $t$, and the zeros of the second term are easy to find.

Comment: how did you come up with this / why do you care about the result? Just curious or is it part of another problem? :-)

Comment: In your small examples you have $t_{n+1} \le t_n+5$.  Maybe you should ask if $t_{n+1}$ is ever greater than $t_n+5$

Answer (score 2):

Your function can be written in the form
$$x(t)={2e^{t/2}\over30\,000}\left(\cos{\sqrt{3}t\over2}+{1\over2}e^{-3t/2}\right)\ .$$
It is then obvious that the equation $x(t)=0$ has only finitely many negative solutions (if at all) and that for $t\to\infty$ the solutions get more and more evenly spaced with distance ${2\pi\over\sqrt{3}}\doteq3.63$.